# Using a php sendmail script, mail sends, but there is no form content in the email

Tags: php, forms, sendmail

I am using the following script to send php sendmail for a very large form.  It sends the email, gives confirmation, but the email does not contain any of the form fields.  I am a novice with php so don't know how to fix it.

I've tried other scripts, but none even send...so I'm back to this one.  I don't know enough php to fix it. This form is supposed to submit through a CMS page in Open Realty.  It did work until the host removed their sendmail script and said it needed to be switched to a php sendmail instead due to upgrades.

```
<?php   

if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
{
} 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
echo "Bad email value!";
exit;
}

$email_from = $_POST['email']; //<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Application from PRN ";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user 
$name.\n".

$to = 'test@example.com';//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: http://example.com/example/index.php? 
action=page_display&amp;PageID=23');

?>
```

A shortened version of the form in html, form is long:

```
<form method="post" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email.php"> 

 <p><input name="Volunteer Form" type="hidden" value="Volunteer Application" /> <label>Name <input id="name" name="name" size="48" style="width: 604px; height: 28px;" type="text" /> </label></p>

<p><label>Address: <input id="address" name="address" size="15" style="width: 583px; height: 28px;" type="text" /> </label></p>
 <label> <input id="community_events" name="community_events" type="checkbox" /> Represent PRN at Community Events</label> <label> <input id="baker" name="baker" type="checkbox" /> Baker</label><br />
<label><input id="other" name="other" type="checkbox" /> Other - Specify in Comments Section</label> <label> <input id="any_way" name="any_way" type="checkbox" /> Willing to help in any way that helps the Pugs. Just ask!</label></p>

<p align="left">Please list any skills you may have that would help the Pug Rescue Network (i.e. sewing, scrapbooking)</p>

<p align="left"><label><textarea cols="75" id="any_skills" name="any_skills" rows="5"></textarea></label></p>

<p align="left">Comments:</p>

<p align="left"><label><textarea cols="75" id="comments" name="comments" rows="5"></textarea></label></p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /><input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="http://example.com/example/index.php?action=page_display&amp;PageID=23 " /></p>
</form>
```

This is the email I receive. (to, from headers are fine) Instead of the form, it shows the email it sends to.  There are 3 different long forms on the site and if possible, would like to use the same send mail script to submit all of them. (Application, Volunteers, Fosters)

EMAIL Message:

You have received a new message from the user example.

Here is the message:

test@example.com

Answer (score -1):

Didn't you forget to add the $message var to $email_body??

`"You have received a new message from the user " .$name."\n" . $message;`

Comment: I didn't write the script...not sure I understand what you mean?  I added $message to that line and it no longer would submit.  Is there somewhere else it should be added?  I have very limited php knowledge - learning in bits and pieces  How do I add $message var to $email_body?

Comment: replace the $email_body line with this

$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user " .
$name . $message;

Comment: I did change that as you suggested however it still submits the email, but no form. 
 The email says:   You have received a new message from the user (name).  and nothing more.    It still shows the name, just not the form.  Could it be something on the server stripping off the form?  They told me they won't help unless I tell them what needs to be installed/changed, which I don't have enough experience to do.  (Hostgator)